# how to make angular2 code work on my domain - created by angular-cli

Tags: angular

I am a beginner on angular2. Right now, I used [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) to generate my angular2 project. However, when I tried to move my project onto web server with real domain name, my code doesn't work. It just shows me "loading..."

I hope that when I type my domain url, my home page can be showed up directly.

So far, I just copy and paste all the files into the my web server. When I enter my website, it gave me a list of folder.

[image]

Does anyone have tutorial for this situation? I really appreciate anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to copy the whole project!

Use `ng build -prod` and then everything is build and moved to the `dist` folder.

Just use that output on your webserver.

Comment: This helps me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to build the project and then deploy the build output.
- If you use `PathLocationStrategy` (default) the server needs to support HTML5 pushState. You can try switching to `HashLocationStrategy` which doesn't require server support.
- Is your Angular2 app served at the root path or a sub-directory? You might adjust the `<base href="...">` path.